# increasing maximum probability decreases entropy?

Tags: probability, entropy

Let $p=(p_k)$ and $q=(q_k)$ be discrete probabilities. Let $q_{\max} > p_{\max}$. Then $H(q) < H(p)$?

I tried to prove it algebraically but failed. Is it supposed to be difficult?

Note for clarification that $p=(p_k)_{k=1}^K$, $\sum_k p_k = 1$ with $1 \ge p_k\geq 0$, and $H(p) = -\sum_k p_k \log p_k$.

Comment: What do you mean by "discrete probability densities"?  I have a couple of ideas but both would suggest the implication was not generally true

Comment: @Henry I clarified a bit. If you have a counterexample, please save me by suggesting one.

Comment: @Henry Sorry my bad really. They are just probabilities, not densities.

Comment: As stated, seems false to me too. Take $q = (2/3, 1/6, 1/6)$ vs $p = (1/2, 1/2, 0)$. $e$-based entropies are 0.87 and 0.69.

Although possibly if you increase the max probability and decrease other probabilities proportionally, then my guess is the entropy would indeed decrease.

Comment: $H()$ can be arbitrarily large just by having many, many possibilities (each with non-zero probability).  Imagine $q_{max} > 1/2$ and then having a billion other $q_i$ each with tiny probability, then $H(q)$ will be very large.

Comment: No, that's not true in general, that $q_{max} > p_{max}$ implies $H_q < H_p$.

Take for example, $p=(1/2,1/3,1/6)$ and $q=(0.502, 0.249, 0.249).$

Then $H_p=1.011404$ and $H_q=1.038326$. The uniformity of probabilities other than the maximal increases the entropy.